# invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' using std::sort

Tags: c++, string, sorting, char, stl-algorithm

```
 #include <stdio.h>
   #include <algorithm>
   #include <string.h>
   using namespace std;
   #define MAX 1000000
   char s[MAX+1][21],sir[MAX+1];

   bool cmp( char a[21],char b[21]) {
      return strcmp(a, b) < 0;
    }

    int main()
    {
        FILE *fin,*fout;

        fin=fopen("rocker.in","r");
        fout=fopen("rocker.out","w");

        int i,j,n,k,l,ind;
        char ch;

        fscanf(fin,"%d%d",&n,&k);
        fscanf(fin,"%c",&ch);
        fgets(sir,MAX,fin);

        for(i=0;i<k;i++)
            s[0][i]=sir[i];
        ind=k-1;
        for(i=1;i<n-k+1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<k-1;j++)
                s[i][j]=s[i-1][j+1];
            s[i][k-1]=sir[++ind];
        }

        sort(s[0],s[n-k+1],cmp);

        for(i=0;i<n-k+1;i++)
        {
            j=0;
            while(j<k&&s[i][j]==s[i+1][j])
                j++;
            j--;
            fprintf(fout,"%d\n",j);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Doing this always gets me this error and I couldn't find a way to fix it.

> error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]|

I believe it has to do with the way I pass the strings as parameters.

I have already tried to swap `char a[21]` with `char *` but that wasn't any better.

Thanks!

Comment: Provide full code, without it's just guessing.

Comment: Try `sort(s, s+n-k+1, cmp);`

Comment: use `vector` and `string`.

Comment: Use C++, not C. To be fair, you did use a C++ standard algorithm, but do not stop there. Also use its containers, iterators and file I/O.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this:

```
char s[MAX+1][21];
std::sort(s[0], s[n-k+1], cmp);
```

The `sort` function will swap elements in an array to make it sort. But it can only swap simple types including pointers, but not an array. For example this will fail and not copy 21 bytes:

```
s[2] = s[1]; // error
```

Instead you have to use a pointer allocate memory for it.

```
char * s[MAX+1];
for(int i=0; i<MAX+1; i++)
    s[i] = new char[21];
```

Now `s[i]` is just a pointer and can be swapped with other entries in the array.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think sort((char**)s,(char**)(&s[n-k+1]),cmp); is what you want to do. It's can compile But it can not function as you expected. you should know bool cmp( char a[21],char b[21]) is exactly equal to bool cmp( char* a,char* b). and the string compare expect \0 ended